# Execution Failed for task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac in React Native

Tags: react-native

```
i install react navigation version 6 and i want to use drawer navigation in project 
for that install all packages of drawer navigation and make changes  in
babel.congile file  =  plugins: ["react-native-reanimated/plugin"],


Second change in MainActivity.java file
```

"import android.os.Bundle;"

"import com.facebook.react.bridge.JSIModulePackage"
"import com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedJSIModulePackage"

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(null);
}
@Override
protected JSIModulePackage getJSIModulePackage() { 
      return new ReanimatedJSIModulePackage(); 
    }
}
also i changes the andrion app  buid.gradlew 

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]
```

when remove all these changes then Project buid succeeded and run

```
when i use the JS Module Packages then i face the above error
so My React native version 0.67
so any body can helper
```

Answer (score 0):

hi @waqas i think  you are using the latest version of react native reanimated.

please try to downgrade react native reanimated version to
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.2",

may be helps this;

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to this GitHub thread https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210. It worked for me!

The steps I followed:

- Deleted node_modules
- Changed "react-native" package version (in the package.json file) from "0.70.1" to the latest patch I found in the thread (that was "0.70.5" for me)
- Ran `npm install` to generate again the node_modules folder (you may want to use `yarn install` if your project is based on yarn packages)
- Then `cd android` && `./gradlew clean`
- Finally `cd ..` (back to root folder) and `npm run android` to build the app.

Note that I followed the instructions for React Native >= 0.63 (version)

Hope this works for somebody else too!